# Не удается выполнить pip install mysqlclient

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

Windows 10 64bit

Python 3.8.1

MySQL 8.0

Запускаю

```powershell
$ pip install mysqlclient
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
```

Падает с ошибкой. Пробовала установить [отсюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) - получаю ошибку:

```powershell
$ pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
ERROR mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

Не знаю, что делать. Как установить **mysqlclient**? Где и как взять этот файл *mysql.h*?

Comment: Очевидно вам нужен пакет разработки под MySQL. Понятия не имею, как это выглядит в Windows. А Windows у вас 64-битная?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете скачать неофициальные файлы windows для вашей версии python с помощью https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient. Потом установите его с помощью pip. Таким образом, Вы сможете избежать хлопот, связанных с использованием средств сборки visual studio.

Просто скачайте mysqlclient.whl-файл  и запустите

```
pip install " путь к загруженному файлу .whl "
```